# Spring boot kafka producer send large mex

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In some solutions reported on StackOverflow, we are told to increase the `MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG`. In my case it does not help, because the broker cannot be changed: it is set to receive 1 MB messages.

Can we send a message with a larger size? We tried multiple compressions but did not work. Below our configuration and some snippets of code.

ProducerConfig

```java
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, servers);
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientID);
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, acks);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, batchSize);
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retries);
props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, compression);
props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, requestTimeout);
props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, transactionTimeout);
props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, maxBlock);

props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
```

We send a message in the following format:

```java
public class Test {
    private Class1 info;
    private Class3 payLoad;
}
```

I try with this library: [li-apache-kafka-clients](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.linkedin.kafka.clients/li-apache-kafka-clients)

The Producer send correctly the data, but the listener not receive it, because I use a batch listener

```java
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Test> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        
factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
factory.setBatchListener(true);
factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler());
         factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If your payload is text try to compress it first using LZ4

Comment: Payload is another Class Java

Comment: I see that you serialize the object as JSON. Then try to compress the JSON using LZ4 before publishing. For this, you have to create your own Serializer/Deserializer, which is very simple

Comment: @OctavianR. thanks. Can you share me an example please ? because i tried with a class that implements Serializer/Deserializer class but not work